# Conflict between two jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a conflict between a widget collapsible box and a ColorPickerSliders plugins.
This script enables the functioning of the widget box

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
```

and this one the ColorPickerSliders

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
```

together enabled, nothing works. 
The difference appears only in the version of jquery.min.js, but in fact both are used for the operation and none of the 2 plugin works without their jquery.min.js.

I'm sorry but i don't have a demo to show you. I'm working on localhost.
What can i do? Thanks

Comment: When testing locally, you need to specify the http:// protocol.

Comment: Code samples would be helpful and wound save everyone lots of time.

Comment: Include only 1 jQuery then

Answer (score 1):

You should only include one version of jQuery in your page. Of those two, I would suggest you use 1.11.1 as it's the more recent. You also need to make sure the paths to the CDNs are correct. When testing on your local filesystem, this will mean including the protocol where required:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried to use only the 1.11.1, disabling the 1.11.0  but widget box doesn't work

Comment: As mentioned, you need to include the `http://` if testing locally with that URL. I would use the CDN version as per my example, as it is the more commonly used one, and more likely to be cached in the visitors' browser.

Comment: Yes i included the http ahead..but no differents. I will prepare a simple page to show you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [have multiple versions of jquery running on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page), however it is best to avoid it if you can.

Perhaps report to the maintainer of the plugin which doesn't support the newer version of jquery that they have a compatibility issue, as it would also be in their best interest.